# Select2 passing only one select to the form in Django

Tags: django, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using Select2 for a multiple select for tags. I'm using Taggit for the tags. The problem is that if a user chooses more than one tag, then just one is passed to the form.

My select HTML:

```
<select class="custom-select js-example-basic-multiple form-control " id="select-tags" name="usertags" multiple="multiple">
                    {% for tag in userTags %}
                    <option value="{{ tag }}" data-id="{{ tag.color }}" class="options">{{ tag }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
```

My form:

```
class FileUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Uploaded
        fields = (
            'name',
            'file',
            'usertags',
        )
```

Views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.user = request.user
        user = request.user
        form.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your options need to have unique ids.

```
<option value="yyxx" id="xx">option name</option>
```

Comment: I've added an ID but it still doesn't work. Also, select2 seems to generate a unique id for each option on itself.

Comment: how did you fix this @BoostedAnimal ? I don't know how it's working with forms but if you use `request.POST.getlist('usertags')` you can see the result posted as a list